# Measuring Entropy of an image

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

I have noticed in MatLab you can call a function to measure entropy of an image.

I am using Emgu/C# and I have been looking for a way to do the same with that framework.

Does anyone know how it can be done please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want Shannon Entropy for an arbitrary file, there's no built in function for this in C# (or Emgu to my knowledge).

But it's not hard to find some simple implementations online, such as [this one](http://csharpcodewhisperer.blogspot.in/2013/07/Data-Entropy.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for that link. I shall look into that and learn what it does